# accessing value of collapse:not(.show) { display: none; }

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to use `getElementsByClassName` to get the value of the `display` style in:

```css
.collapse:not(.show) { 
  display: none; 
}
```

My code is:

```
document.getElementById("whatever").getElementsByClassName("collapse:not(.show)");
```

This didn't work. My desired outcome is to return `none`. What can I do?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` takes class names, not selectors. Use `querySelectorAll` or `querySelector` to, well, query on selectors...

Answer (score 1):

[`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) queries the document for elements that have the specified *class name*, but you've provided a class name along with part of a [*selector*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (i.e., `collapse` is the class name, and `:not(.show)` is a CSS selector).

Here's how you could get the `display` style of those elements:

1. Query the document for all elements matching the given selector using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
2. Get the computed style of each element with [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), which returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration`.
3. Get the value of the `display` style with [`CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue).

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse:not(.show)') //  1️⃣
for (const elem of elems) {
  const styles = window.getComputedStyle(elem) // 2️⃣
  const display = styles.getPropertyValue('display') // 3️⃣
  console.log(elem, { display })
}
```

```css
.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="collapse">Item 1</li>
  <li class="collapse show">Item 2</li>
  <li class="collapse">Item 3</li>
  <li class="collapse show">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```